# FTP via PHP Error

Tags: php, html, upload, ftp, web

I am having an issue with uploading to FTP from my website through PHP.

**It connects OK**, but then has an issue with the uploading of the image.

**HTML**

```
<form action="../scripts/php/saveupload.php" method="post">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$ftp_server = "XXXXXX";
$ftp_user_name = "XXXXX";
$ftp_user_pass = "XXXXX";
$destination_file = "/public_html/img/news/";
$source_file = $_FILE['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

//check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The message I am getting is:

> "Connected to ftp.theucl.co.uk, for user theucl.co.ukFTP upload has
>   failed!"

[This is now the error I am getting after following Niths advice on the error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMFQN.png)

It appears the error is around the following..

```
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

and

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $source_file,FTP_ASCII);
```

Obviously there's a common apperance amongst this

Comment: Those aren't your real credentials...are they?

Comment: Check folder permission .I guess current permission is set to 755.Set it to 777

Comment: I would recommend against setting permissions to 777. It's a security risk. Though checking folder permissions are correct is valid.

Comment: Hi, please read my answer, if you need any additional info please ping me ASAP.

Comment: @JonStirling no they're not. Secondly my host doesn't appear to have an option on the control panel for folder checking.

Comment: @NithyanandhanM 
 
I changed as you said and then received an FTP Connection error. I edited the $update to the one I had, and that still connected with the updates but applied the same error as previously with the upload. Initially I had it down as an FTP_Binary instead of FTP_ASCII and that didn't do anything either.

Comment: By default FTP port is 21. Will you please share the error screenshot & code link from runnable site?

Comment: And Note that i have tested in internal server only(localhost) & Not server running in other machine or other location & use alphanumeric ftp credentials.

Comment: You have to use error handler functions to check why upload failed? For example, include following code in top of file. ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
print_r(error_get_last());

Comment: Hi @NithyanandhanM I have updated the original question with the update from that!

Comment: Hi @Sam Anderson, Did you included the following code in form open tag, enctype="multipart/form-data". Please check with my answer HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a tutorial on Youtube by Thorn Web... instead of altering what I had above I restarted it and now have the following:

```
<?php

    if($_POST['submit']){

        $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        $temp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
        $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'];

        if(($type == "image/jpeg") || ($type == "image/jpg") || ($type == "image/gif")){

                if($size <= 1000000){

                    move_uploaded_file($temp, "../img/news/$name");


                }else{

                    echo "The file: '<b>$name</b>' is too big...<br>
                    The size is <b>$size</b> and needs to be less than 100GB. ";
                }       
        }else{
            echo "This type '<b>$type</b>' is not allowed";
        }
    }

?>
```

This works a treat

Answer (score 0):

There are few corrections in your code. Check the destination folder permission where you are uploading the files. Confirm that folder have writable permission. **IF upload failed, please check with error handler and do the necessary changes such as create upload destination folder, assign file permission etc **

First in your html form add enctype type.

**HTML**

```
<form action="../scripts/php/saveupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input name="file" type="file" />
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

And then in php file totally 3 changes. I have printed those lines below. Just compare those three changes with your code. In your program the **$source_file** says **$_FILE** is undefined. And, I used **ftp port 21** in **ftp_connect()** function. In **ftp_put()** use 4th variable as **FTP_ASCII** or **FTP_BINARY**

```
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,21);
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file.$_FILES['file']['name'], $source_file,FTP_ASCII);
```

For full program

**PHP**

```
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    print_r(error_get_last());

    $ftp_server = "XXXXXX";
    $ftp_user_name = "XXXXX";
    $ftp_user_pass = "XXXXX";
    $destination_file = "/public_html/img/news/";
    $source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,21);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

    // check connection
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
        exit; 
    } else {
        echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
    }

    // upload the file 
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file.$_FILES['file']['name'], $source_file,FTP_ASCII); 

    // check upload status
    if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
    } else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
    }

    // close the FTP stream 
    ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I read many articles and found that **username** and **password** should contains only **alpha numeric**. Also i tried **$ftp_server** as your **localhost**.

So to check with the program, try in any internal server (one for both running php file and the same server for ftp file transfering). I know there is no use of same server as FTP for file transfer. But you please try uploading file in same server. If the FTP process works fine, then we will try changing ftp server.

Comment: [Above is the webpage error that occurs when attempting to upload the image, below is the script.][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vxFt2.png